# Carrierwave - "uploading" a file from a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, carrierwave

Users in my site can upload their own photos for a model or choose from a library. When the users choose from the library I send the file name as a string to the server `{file: {url: 'url.jpg'}}`. I haven't find a way in which carrierwave can just update a model file without uploading it. I can write a condition in my model that checks for the existence of that parameter and then `model.file = File.open('str.jpg')`. Is that bad from a security view? How can I "upload" files, or just update the file attribute, to reference a file that's already available on the server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution of using `File.open` would work, but you should verify that the name is valid with `File.basename` so someone couldn't pass `../../secret_credentials.yml` and expose info you don't want them to. Also checking it against the list of preset images would be a good idea.

However, you can do this more efficiently by skipping CarrierWave in this case.

Add a new field called `library_image`, when someone wants to use a preset image, then you set `library_image`, if they want to use their own photo, unset `library_image` and upload the photo as normal. Then add a helper method like:

```
def avatar_url
    if self.library_image?
        "http://example.com/images/#{self.library_image}"
    else
        self.picture.url
    end
end
```

This assumes that you can find the preset images at `http://example.com/images/[name]` and you are using `mount_uploader` in CarrierWave named `picture`.

Now anytime you want to display their picture, you would call `avatar_url` which will check if it should return the preset URL, or the picture they uploaded.

An example of how you would update `library_image` or `picture` based on your original question:

```
if params[:file].is_a?(Hash)
    model.library_image = params[:file][:url]
    model.remove_picture = true
else
    model.library_image = nil
    model.picture = params[:file]
end
```

Comment: How can I detect that the user is uploading a new picture? I mean, what's the callback function name I should write to reset the library_image? Thank you!

Comment: @CamelCamelCamel I've updated my original answer with an example.

Comment: How do I return file as either the preset or the file depending on avatar_url?

Answer (score 3):

I would make another resource called LibraryImages wich holds these image files.

These would be in a relation with the User class using the `has_many` association.
the second is to seperate when a user wants to use its own image instead of a pre defined one.

therefor I would suggest adding a boolean type called 'use_library', once they choose to use their own image it will just upload to the user.image without any problems.

now in your view just ask if the use_library returns true if so use `image_tag(user.library_image)`